# How is Hina related to Maui in Hawaiian mythology?

Tags: hawaiian

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=M%C4%81ui_(Hawaiian_mythology)&oldid=752355988):

> he is the son of ʻAkalana and his wife Hina-a-ke-ahi (Hina)

and according to [Encyclopedia Mythica](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/m/maui.html):

> Maui's mother Hina complained that the sun traveled too fast across the sky.

However, in the tale of Tuna,the eel god, Hina is the wife of Maui. And in another tale, Hina is the sister of him who lends him her hair to make a net to trap the Sun. How exactly is Hina related to Maui in Hawaiian mythology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hina depending on where you get the story could be the grandmother in other Polynesian cultures, but Hina yes in Hawaiian mythology Hina is Maui's mother. You can see relations of Maui to Hina in this story by W. D. Westervelt in *Legends of Maui:* http://www.sacred-texts.com/pac/maui/maui04.htm